# Eclipse PDT 3.6 Helios, keyboard shortcuts for toggle comment not working any more

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-pdt

Since upgrading Eclipse PDT from 3.5 to 3.6 my toggle comment/block comment shortcuts
(<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>) in Editors view, are not working any more. I can see them in the Menu

```
Source > Toggle Commtent (Ctrl + /)
```

as well as in the context menu accessible via

```
Shift + Ctrl + L
```

But they simple don't work any more.

Has anybody the same problems? And is there a solution out there for this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a solution for this in the attached eclipse forum posts.

You simply have to download

org.eclipse.php.ui_2.2.1.v20101001-2300.jar

from

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/pdt/updates/2.2/milestones/plugins/org.eclipse.php.ui_2.2.1.v20101001-2300.jar

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/pdt/updates/2.2/milestones/plugins/org.eclipse.php.debug.core.source_2.2.0.v20101001-2300.jar

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/pdt/updates/2.2/milestones/plugins/org.eclipse.php.debug.core_2.2.0.v20101001-2300.jar

and start eclipse with -clean command

cd /path/to/eclipse

eclipse -clean

**Eclipse Forum posts**

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=205571&S=d1aa5d2748a6d8ee2064c340ec8eaa88#page_top

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=205375&start=0&S=ef58561fd3814f61bc3386addebba90c

Comment: The solution by Jeremy S. works perfectly. I am only posting to further clarify. Download org.eclipse.php.ui_2.2.1.v20101001-2300.jar from http://sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/releases/51060 Place this jar in the eclipse/plugins directory to overwrite the JAR. Then run the command
/path/to/eclipse/eclipse -clean

Comment: Thanks for this, I followed your instructions (and thanks to the comment above as well) - problem fixed!

Comment: This download is no longer available.

Comment: You should just be able to update your PDT plugin now and it will be fixed.  My guess is there was a conflict with the latest version of Eclipse, but the PDT team must have solved it since we last installed the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

This solution doesn't work with the latest Helios release anymore

steps to reproduce:

1. download - http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-362/heliossr2
2. install JAVA and PHP development tools (via update)
3. download http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/pdt/update/2.2/milestones/plugins/org.eclipse.php.ui_2.2.1.v20101001-2300.jar
4. overwrite the existing file in eclipse/plugin
5. run eclipse with the -clean option
6. switch to PHP perspective
7. create a new php project, create a new php file
8. toggle comment no longer works

here's the bug report on eclipse.org https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=360526

Comment: acerbiter is right. I tried this solution and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I use eclipse kepler (CDT) in opensuse 12.3 and I too can't produce // at the beginning of an actual line by Ctrl+/. However Ctrl+Shift+7 works because on my key-board the key '/' must be typed as Shift+7.

A solution for me was the more simplier short-cut Ctrl+7 installed by 
Windows|Preferences|General|Keys|Comment/Uncomment ...
The disadvatange is that Ctrl+7 is a new short-cut.

To comment a text block I first marked it and then I used the
short-cut Strg+Shift+7, also installed by
Windows|Preferences|General|Keys|Add Block Comment ...

I hope this can help You!?